# What is difference between Notification Channel Priority and Notification Priority in Android | Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, notifications

I am learning to work with notifications in Android. I came to know that Notification Channel and Notifications itself needs a priority value. So, I want to know what is the difference between? Or what will happen when I change Channel Priority or Notificaiton Priority?

I tried with Default priority value first for both Notifications and Notification Channel and then changed both to High, but not able to see any difference.

Answer (score 3):

As per [android docs](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/channels#importance), Notification Priority is used only on devices running Android 7.1 (API level 25) or lower. On higher android versions Notification Channel Importance is used.

Comment: okay, but we still set priority for notifications for devices higher than 7.1, right?

Comment: if you min sdk version is greater than 25, you don't need to set priority for notifications.